# local yum repo dosenot update package

Tags: linux, centos, yum

i've my local repo which serve my serves , strange thing , ive added new package ( update for old version )
when ever i try to update i always get  No Packages marked for Update

here is my base repo config

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
baseurl=http://CentOS/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
#gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates
baseurl=http://CentOS/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
```

As Edition :

```
curl -I http://CentOS/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 28 Sep 2014 07:41:03 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Last-Modified: Mon, 11 Feb 2013 08:48:56 GMT
ETag: "148211-5-4d56efab30e00"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 5
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Please advise do i miss anything make my yum server not picking updated packages  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to rerun createrepo on your local server, or run
    yum clean all
on your client.